# SUDO command only works as root (Solaris 10)

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, solaris-10, command

After installing sudo in the system i am unable tu run sudo as a non-root user, when i try to execute any command i get:

/usr/local/bin/sudo: cannot execute

if i edit /etc/passwd to use a different shell i get:

/usr/local/bin/sudo: permission denied

the sudoers file seems to be correctly configured since the output of "sudo -l -U user" shows the user is able to execute only the commands i want it to use.

ls -l output is:

-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 205396 Oct 8 2010 /usr/local/bin/sudo

Comment: try adding permissions to sudo for non root users to execute.  that file looks like it can only be executed by the user root in the group root.

Comment: i reinstalled sudo and now permission look exactly the same as another working system: ---s--x--x 1 root root 217072 Sep 6 2010 /usr/local/bin/sudo, but the problem persist

Comment: i tried what you said, i created another group and made it owner of the file...still cant be executed except by those in root group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the folder:
/usr/local/bin
It did not have the right permissions, once I corrected this "sudo" ran without problems.